# unable to access nfs files from web browser when selinux is enables

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, selinux

i am able to access html pages from nfs mounted volume on my amazon ec2 centos instance when selinux is disabled. But when i enable it, i get "could not connect" error. I have enabled httpd_use_nfs and other related boolean policies, but still getting the same error.Please help me resolving the issue. I need apache to access my web pages with SELinux On.

Comment: What is in your auditlog at /var/log/audit/audit.log ?

Comment: thanks for responding.Here is a portion of audit.log

Comment: thanks for the response.here is a portion of audit.log related to httpd.type=AVC msg=audit(1392816609.757:94): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6424 comm="httpd" path="/home/testman" dev=0:13 ino=393960 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=dir./home/testman is the mount point.forgive my ignorance,do i have to look at anything else in the logfile?

Comment: Well, httpd cannot access home directories by default, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566234/selinux-enforcing-not-honouring-httpd-enable-homedirs-off how to enable. However, I do not recommend access home directory that way. If it is possible, rather to mount to another mountpoint and label it. Or have a look, how to access a label directory described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795410/proper-way-to-set-selinux-with-apache-virtualhost-reading-from-a-mount

Comment: thank you. will take a look into the links.

Answer (score 0):

How check if the problem is generated by selinux :

```
setenforce 0 # if it works after this command : Selinux is the problem
setenforce 1 # re-enable selinux because you are not crazy
```

How resolve the problem of selinux :

```
# install setroubleshoot (here for centos7)
yum install setroubleshoot
#audit
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep sealert
```

Read the last message and you can execute the command proposed to resolve your problem.

Generally, after, the problem is resolved.

SeLinux is simple...sometimes...  ;-)